# Rails pdf file display

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, download

I am working on uploading/downloading files in Rails 3.x and storing the uploaded files in MySQL db. Pdf and doc files are stored in Binary/Image i.e BLOB format.

I am facing problem in displaying the contents of pdf file on the browser.

Code for displaying pdf on browser (controller) :

```
@attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])
    send_data(@attachment.data,
    :filename => @attachment.filename,
    :type => @attachment.content_type,
    :disposition => "inline")
```

Output : Either file is NOT displayed or it says" file is damaged, cannot be repaired"

Any suggestions ??

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey try changing datatype of column in mysql from blob to longblob & following in view :

```
  <% elsif (attachment.content_type==('application/pdf')) %>
           <td> <embed src="<%=url_for(:action => 'pdfshow', :id => attachment.id)  %>" width="80%" height='500'> </td>
```